# React Native and require('http')

Tags: react-native

The node core shipped with React Native does not seem to include node core http. Is it possible to add it and use at all within React Native?

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you need to do? Could you use the react native network polyfill? http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#content

Comment: Thanks, Colin. I would like to use some libraries (one being pouchdb) that require the http module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're stuck at the moment. My understanding is that while React Native uses nodejs to get up and running, the runtime isn't *actually* nodejs, which is why you can't just `require` http.

This closed issue says pretty much that, with regards to `util` and `request` from nodejs:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/375

Comment: Indeed it's not node.  It's easier to treat it more like a browser to be honest, for example use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` api instead.

Comment: but is there a solution to it ?

Answer (score 17):

According to the react-native team,

> For this specific case you'll likely want to use the fetch API which
>   is provided by the environment. React Native does not run inside of
>   the node runtime.

`fetch` works similarly to `http`. Here is a short example of how to use it:

```js
// Using fetch to POST

fetch(requestURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    message: this.state.input,
  })
 })

// Using fetch to GET

fetch(requestURL)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
      loaded: true,
    });
  })
   .done();
```

Comment: it is interesting to see that their examples are obsolete already where require('fetch') is not required anymore. Fetch func is in build as far as I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this module: https://github.com/peter4k/react-native-backbone. It use backbone concept and has some http method.