# Using PubNub with React Native

Tags: react-native, pubnub

Has anybody been able to integrate PubNub with React Native?

The PubNub support team told me to use the [pubnub_browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubnub_browserify) package and it should work. However when I do `require('pubnub_browserify')` I get an error that the `http` module could not be found:

`Unable to resolve module http from /Users/jfender/Documents/Workspace/KaiwaReact/node_modules/pubnub_browserify/browserify_node/pubnub.js: Invalid directory /Users/node_modules/http`

Running `npm install http --save` doesn't change the error.

I am using Node v5.1.0, npm 3.3.12 and React Native 0.14.2.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "KaiwaReact",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^1.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.9.0",
    "parse": "^1.6.9",
    "parse-react": "^0.5.0",
    "pubnub_browserify": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.14.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: this looks suspicious... "http": "0.0.0"

Comment: @ChrisGeirman Ah, that's what I got after `npm install http --save`. Updating question to remove that line.

Comment: Try: `npm install agentkeepalive --save` and see if that works. It says one of the dependencies is agentkeepalive...

Comment: @Dair Nope, no luck there. Although I did see `WARN engine agentkeepalive@0.2.4: wanted: {"node":"0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"5.1.0","npm":"3.3.12"})` when installing.

Comment: Seems like there is a duplicate issue on StackOverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371694/react-native-and-requirehttp

Answer (score 2):

I was able to integrate it. I used the standard javascript package. However, I did need to modify it a bit. Mostly to remove all the references to 'window' and to 'abort'. Once I removed those, I was good to go.

Comment: Nicely played, sir. Perhaps you could PR this on our repo? Not required but would be appreciated. Cheers, Craig.

Comment: @CraigConover Sure, just create a new repo for react native and I'll make a pull request to it.

Comment: @eyal83 Hiii, any chance you can help me out with making react-native open a connection with Pubnub ? Thank you !

Comment: Is this SO thread helpful?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547779/react-native-pubnub-webrtc-video-chat

Comment: And we are working on additional React-Native content to assist with this.

Answer (score 0):

PubNub has a new Javascript SDK (v4). You should be able to add the dependency in your package.json file and import it in your code. Here's a quick example of an app that is subscribing to a PubNub channel.

https://github.com/girishd/ReactPubNub

Answer (score -1):

Please try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubnub (version 3.7.16)
(npm install pubnub)
This version works with react-native

Comment: @davendram I've run `npm install pubnub --save` and adding `var PubNub = require("pubnub");` to my index JS file and it returns `Unable to resolve module pubnub`.

Comment: @davendram I downgraded to Node v4.2.2 and npm 2.14.7 to avoid using the flat modules structure to see if that helped. No luck there either, still getting the same error.

Comment: We are working on new content to assist here. Stay tuned for new response.

Comment: Installed pubnub but there's a dependency on `crypto` and I'm stuck due to that. Noted at https://github.com/girishd/ReactPubNub/issues/1