# React-native pubnub WebRTC Video Chat

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, pubnub

I work on a mobile application (react-native+pubnub) to make a WebRTC Video Chat . my problem is that pubnub doesn't have a specific SDK for `react-native`, how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

## Bundling PubNub SDK in Your React-Native Apps

Not the answer you might be looking for but here are some links that should show you how to bundle PubNub JS SDK in your react-native app.

- [Getting Started With React and Rangle’s Starter Kit](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-06-14-getting-started-with-pubnub-and-react/)
- [SO Thread: Using PubNub with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843542/using-pubnub-with-react-native) - see the last answer in the thread.
- [Upcoming PubNub Live Webinar: React Dev Training: Building a Realtime App with React and PubNub](https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/8153437647053025793?source=WC-CY16-Q3-Blog-Hellobar)

We are in the early states of a React-Native SDK. If you have any further issues using PubNub in your React-Native application, feel free to contact [PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/support) directly.